# LaTeX seems to insert an extra inter word space before a capital letter in the middle of a word

Tags: spacing

But I guess it doesn't and it's just a font issue that makes the combination look like there was a space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\textit{vajra\-kapāla\-dhāri\-dvi\-bhujai\-ka\-mukha\-rakta\-Vajravārāhī\-samāpannam}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

What are my possibilities to reduce the space here?

Comment: The manual one is along the lines of `...rakta\-\kern-1.5pt Vajrav...`. A fancier one would be to rely on one or more of the options from `microtype`'s section on 'micro fine tuning'.

Comment: @jon The manual solution looks fine, and it's just one odd word. Any possible side effects of it I should be aware of?

Comment: I think you're fine with `\kern`. It works in both vertical and horizontal mode, and all you're doing is adding a little negative space in this case. One concern is that, because it is a manual and ad hoc hack, if the font changes, you'll probably need to revisit how much negative kerning you need/want to add.

Comment: @jon Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answered in comments.)

> The manual one is along the lines of `...rakta\-\kern-1.5pt Vajrav...`. A fancier one would be to rely on one or more of the options from `microtype`'s section on 'micro fine tuning'.

One drawback of the 'manual' solution is that a change in the font might mean you'll want to revisit how much negative kerning is required.